# Unfitting output of String manipulation

Tags: java, string, collections

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.ListIterator;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.StringTokenizer;

 public class N12 {
    public String reverseWords(String s) {

    String value = "";
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        list.add(st.nextToken());
    }


    ListIterator lt = list.listIterator();

    while (lt.hasPrevious()) {
        String t = (String) lt.previous();
        System.out.println(t);
        sb.append(t);
    }
    value = sb.toString();
    return value;
 }

 public static void main(String ss[]) {
    N12 sol = new N12();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String s1 = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println(sol.reverseWords(s1));
 }
```

}

I want to reverse the string as word by word. I got the string and stored it using StringTokenizer. For reversing the string from last word, i have used hasPrevious() and previous() methods of ListIterator. It shows nothing.  If I use hasNext() and next() instead, it's working properly.

(e.g.)
Input: 
I am back

Output:
back am I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use hasPreviews() because you're starting at the begining of the list. You need to start at the end.
Try to use :

```
ListIterator lt = list.listIterator(list.size());
```